# Installing Windows 7 alongside an existing Ubuntu OS

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Windows 7 after I’ve installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

How can I install windows 7 along with my existing Ubuntu 10.04 OS?

Comment: Insert the Windows 7 boot device and install it. For sure Windows loves to destroy Linux when you're installing it but even in the installation setup of Windows you got a partition managment tool.

Comment: What have you tried?  Steps zero and one would be backing up data and resizing the partition to make room for the second OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you first install windows and then try installing ubuntu, you get both sistems working just fine. But if you try to install windows after installing ubuntu, windows installer will format your hard drive so you will loose your ubuntu installation.

There is a way to do it, anyhow, but is not easy and you will need a different physical hard disk. If your computer does not support more than one hard disk (most laptops don't) you won't get it working.

I've done it a long time ago, so I can't remember every step, but it should be something like this:

- First replace your hard disk with the one you want to install windows on.
- Install Windows on that hard drive.
- When you have done the new installation, put the old Ubuntu hard disk back where it was.
- Connect the hard disk where you have just installed windows in the secondary hard disk  slot of your motherboard.

And that's it. If everything went ok, GRUB should recognize the new Windows installation, so you can choose it when you turn on your computer.

I hope that helps.